# Angular2 http delete returns 404

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

I have a list with objects, in my case actors. Each actor has e delete button. Whenever i click on this it's supposed to delete the object from te json file on my api and instantly refresh the list so the deleted object is not shown anymore. However my delete function returns a 404 error and i can't seem to understand why exactly.

**component file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Actor } from '../../model/actor';
import { ActorService } from '../../service/actor.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './actor-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./actor-list.component.scss']
})


export class ActorListComponent implements OnInit {
  actors: Actor[];
  selectedActor: Actor;
    constructor(private actorService: ActorService) { }

    getActors(): void {
        this.actorService.getActors().then(actors => this.actors = actors);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getActors();
    }
    delete(actor: Actor): void {
        this.actorService
            .delete(actor.id)
            .then(() => {
            this.actors = this.actors.filter(a => a !== actor);
            });
    }
}
```

**the html:**

```
<button (click)="delete(actor); $event.stopPropagation()" >
    <fa class="list-btn" [name]="'trash'"></fa>
</button>
```

**and my service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actor } from '../model/actor';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ActorService {
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    private actorsUrl = '/app/persons.json';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    getActors(): Promise<Actor[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.actorsUrl)
            .toPromise().then(response => <Actor[]>response.json().personList)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('Error: ', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message);
    }
    getActor(id: string): Promise<Actor> {
        return this.getActors()
            .then(actors => actors.find(actor => actor.id === id));
    }
    delete(id: string): Promise<void> {
        const options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});
        const url = `${this.actorsUrl}/${id}`;
        console.log('deleting actor ' + id);
        return this.http.delete(url, options)
            .toPromise()
            .then(() => null)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are creating the correct URL? 
404 only occurs when the url is incorrect. Try sending the request with postman. It always helps me.

Comment: or when someone returns NotFound which a lot prefer. If the entity I am trying to delete doesn't exist then return 404. Quite confusing to the client because they need to somehow guess if the URL is wrong or the entity doesn't exist.

Comment: the url worked for both the create and update functions so i didn't think it would be wrong. However, when i deleted the ".json" and the end of private actorsUrl it worked. Seems odd to me considering the url was correct for both update and create but hey it works now!